# AJAX nested listview emptied automatically?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

Been working on this since yesterday morning and cannot pinpoint where's the problem...

I have a master page (index.htm) that contain a link that load my TV Shows list page (list.htm). In this list page, I load in a collapsible the result from an AJAX call to a page (seasons.htm) tha return the seasons list for this show.

If I expand the collapsible in list.htm, the returned collapsible is showed but the content is removed when I try to expand it.

Here's my sample code:

index.htm

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="list.htm">TV Shows List</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

list.htm

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li class="shows" data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Show Test</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" id="show">
                        <!-- Placeholder for Ajax nested listview -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <script language="javascript"> 
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.shows').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
                        $.ajax({ url: "seasons.htm",
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#show").empty().append(data).enhanceWithin().listview("refresh");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

seasons.htm

```
<html>
    <body>
        <li data-role="collapsible">
            <h2>Season 1</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Delete season</a></li>
            "</ul>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is the empty() applying to #show child?

Thank you!

Comment: are you asking if `empty()` empties out all contents of its child? If thats your question, then yes. `empty()` empties out everything in that element... Ask your question better

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my native language. I'll try be clear:

On this line:
 $("#show").empty().append(data).enhanceWithin().listview("refresh");

Why empty() is having some effect on the collapsible appended after the empty() command was use? It should apply to #show only when I expend an object with a class egal to "shows" wich is not the case with the nested collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally make it using this code in list.htm:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li class="shows" data-role="collapsible">
                    <h2>Show Test</h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" id="show">
                        <!-- Placeholder for Ajax nested listview -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <script language="javascript"> 
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $( ".shows" ).collapsible({ expand: function() {
                            $.ajax({ url: "seasons.htm",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $("#show").html(data).enhanceWithin().listview("refresh");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```